# Order By columns from two tables SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables products and sameProducts

```
products
---------------------
id    pro_title      price       seller

sameProducts
----------------------
id    pro_id      price       seller
```

pro_id is the same id as in the products table - id.

Seller inserts a product if it is an existing product then the details are entered in the sameProducts table but if it is a new Product then in products table. I want to get the seller name according to the least price from both the tables for the same pro_id.

Comment: show any simple query you have tried so we can help you more

Comment: There is no question in this post.

Answer (score 0):

```
select seller from(
  select `id`, price, seller from products
  where id = :id
  union
  select pro_id as `id`, price, seller from sameProducts
  where pro_id = :id
) order by price asc limit 1
```

will return the seller name from the row that has the least price with the given id from either table.

however, assuming the name is the same for the given id in each table then it doesn' really make sense to look for the one with the lowest price as they would both have the same name. But you asked for it so here's the code.

Comment: Did you really wrestle a bear once? Pics or it didn't happen.

Comment: twice actually.

Comment: Wouldn't you want to include the product id in the output? I'm a little confused by the question, but the way I understand it, the OP is asking for the cheapest seller per product

Comment: No, he didnt ask for the price he asked for the seller name: "I want to get the seller name."

Answer (score 0):

```
select pro_title , seller,MIN(price) from(
  select * from products
  union
  select products.id as id,pro_title,products.price as price, products.seller as seller from products LEFT JOIN sameProducts where id = pro_id 
) GROUP BY pro_title
```

Comment: This would throw an error because seller is not aggregated

Comment: It looks the same. Seller is still in your SELECT statement but not your GROUP BY. For anything like that, it needs to be aggregated

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do this with a CASE:

```
SELECT p.id,
CASE WHEN (p.price < sp.price OR sp.price IS NULL) THEN p.seller ELSE sp.seller END AS slr
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN sameproducts sp ON p.id = sp.pro_id
```